# Which drone kit is this

Tags: quadcopters, toy-grade-drone

Which drone kit is shown here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJOONKjX9xQ

What are your opinions of it?

R[image: video screen shot 1]

[image: video screen shot 2]

Comment: Opinionated questions don't fit very well with the Stack Exchange's Q&A model, so please don't make this post about that part. We can help with the first part, though

Comment: That looks like a reasonable place to start (assuming it's cheap!). We all flew stuff like that 5 years ago but the market has moved on. Brushed quads are always marginal on power, and the motors need replacing after a year or so. The camera antenna will get bent in crashes, and the picture from these micro cameras isn't as good as the bigger cameras. The transmitter may be some odd protocol that's no compatible with anything else. You don't learn much by 'building' a drone of this size, or save any money. The usual beginner recommendation is the Emax Tiny Hawk.

Comment: Ifconfig I am just trying to learn. @Robin Bennett . Thanks about what all you said and the Emax Tiny Hawk

Comment: No problem, this site works best for questions where there's a definite answer. For opinions I recommend https://www.reddit.com/r/Multicopter/

Comment: Ok. But your answers have been helping me a lot. Will have to be careful not to ask for opinions. But what u said gave me lots of perspective @Robin Bennet. I ask here questions thinking you guys are ahead in experience and whatever u share does enrich my at the moment limited but slowly growing knowledge

Comment: Will check reddit also